# how to create a Salesforce formula that can calculate the highest figure for last month?

Tags: salesforce, formula

in Salesforce, how to create a formula that calculate the highest figure for last month? for example, if I have an object that keeps records that created in Sept, now would like to calculate its max value (in this case, should be 20 on 3/8/2019) in last month's (August). If it's in July, then need to calculate for June. How to construct the right formula expression? Thanks very much!

```
Date       Value
1/9/2019   10
1/8/2019   14
2/8/2019   15
3/8/2019   20
....
30/8/2019  15
```

Comment: Formulas will not be of use here. What you need is a report ordered by your max field descending.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with normal formulas on records because they "see" only current records (and some related via lookup), not other rows in same table.

You could make another object called "accounting periods" or something like that. Link all these entries to periods (months) in master-detail relationship. You'll then be able to use rollup summary with MAX(). Still not great because you need lookup to previous month to pull it but should give you an idea.

You could make a report that achieves something like that. PREVGROUPVAL will let you do some amazing & scary stuff. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/rd-summary-formulas/rd-compare-groups Then... if all you need is a report - great. If you really need it saved somewhere - you could look into [reporting snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) & save results in helper object...

If you want to do it without any data model changes like that master-detail or helper object - you could also write some code. Nightly batch job (running daily? only on 1st day of month?) should be pretty simple.

Without code - in a pinch you could make a Flow that queries records from previous month. Bit expensive to run such thing for August every time you add a September record but if you discarded other options...